# cell override sectionheader view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

i've just created a cell with several cell subclasses, but when i tried to customize header section this weird behaviour occured. Why does the grey from the cell go further than the seperator from the grouped tableView?

this is my code for customizing the header.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayHeaderView:(UIView *)view forSection:(NSInteger)section {
    UITableViewHeaderFooterView *header = (UITableViewHeaderFooterView *)view;

    [[(UITableViewHeaderFooterView*)view backgroundView] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    header.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:14];

    CGRect headerFrame = header.frame;
    header.textLabel.frame = headerFrame;
        header.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;


}
```

Comment: `heightForCell` and `heightForHeader` please.

Comment: have not set any of them, just changed to grouped style in the tableVIew

Comment: What do you expect to happen if you've told the table view that the header view will be 44 pixels big, but you create a larger view? (Or the same thing with cells).

Comment: Nothing seem to change...

Comment: Could it be because header area is bigger than header view? if that how can i change this?